# Почему Select2 multiple не работает в ActiveForm?

Tags: yii2, select2

Доброго времени суток! Подключаю к своему проекту плагин Select2, и столкнулся с такой проблемой, не работает multiple в ActiveForm. При чем без ActiveForm все работает корректно. Устанавливал версию плагина от Kartik-v тоже самое multiple не работает, просто текстовое поле в котором по порядку идут все варианты выбора. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как это исправить? Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась после того, как все, без исключения, стили и скрипты были подключены через файл AppAsset, до этого подключал несколько скриптов на странице с атрибутом defer.